# SSO with ADFS 401 issues

Tags: iis, single-sign-on, adfs

We recently migrated a couple of our MVC apps to SSO using ADFS with basically the following approach: https://www.cloudriven.fi/en/cloud-9-en/how-to-implement-sso-for-asp-net-mvc-application-with-adfs/  I've noticed sometimes when the browser attempts to access a static file, I get a 401 error and the app reverts to NTLM negotiation.  This is okay on our network as the users are logged in and it only seems to happen with a handful of files, however for remote access, this seems to happen for all files and users have to enter their credentials, sometimes several times.  We have another application on another server configured the exact same way with no problems. Has anyone come across this behavior?

**Edit:**  Here is the trace:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AquuuuC3yZ55hkLix_TCaVVblSL8

And the xsl file if anyone needs it:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AquuuuC3yZ55hkNbh3qHdRijQXGy

**Edit 2:**  I have this same configuration running on IIS6 with no problems.  This problem is only occurring on IIS7.

Comment: You should check first what kind of 401 you hit https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 and use FRT to check its source, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Looks like a 401.2.  Do you think you could take a look at the trace and maybe shed some light?